# Using Windows Azure Service Bus be used from an Azure Web Site?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-web-app-service, azureservicebus

[This guide to using Service Bus](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/) says the first step is to create a Service Namespace. I don't see how to do this in the portal for Azure Web Sites. The UI doesn't match the instructions given. I'm wondering if these instructions were written for Web Roles and don't work for Web Sites. Is there another way to do this from a Web Site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When viewing the new Windows Azure portal, move your mouse over the word "Preview" in the topmost navigation bar.

[image: Preview icon in the portal navigation bar]

A dialog should appear. When it does, click the link to take you back to the previous Silverlight portal.

[image: The portal-change link visible in the browser]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was the issue. I had never used the previous portal and didn't even know it existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Silverlight Azure admin portal](https://windows.azure.com), not the [Azure preview portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/). I assume the [Azure preview portal](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/getting-started-with-azure-iaas-and-the-new-windows-azure-portal/5620) will eventually accommodate this change as it nears release.

Comment: Hmmm, that would make sense, but when I go to https://windows.azure.com I get redirected to https://manage.windowsazure.com. I have Silverlight installed. I'm not sure why I can't get to the Silverlight portal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having this issue, please try signing out. When I log on to windows.azure.com, after I sign in, I am presented with a choice as to which portal I want (Preview or the "old portal"). If that doesn't work, you might try clearing your cookies before signing back in.