# Azure Service Bus Free Trial

Tags: windows, service, azure, bus

I have registered, a week ago, for trying windows azure free for 3 months. However I cannot seem to find a menu option for Service Bus or Access Control to create service bus queues and topics. Are these not offered as part of the free trial? I read somewhere that service bus was  part of the free trial only upto May 31st, 2012. Is this true?

Is there any other way to test for free using service bus queues and topics.

Comment: You can find the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530803/using-windows-azure-service-bus-be-used-from-an-azure-web-site?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that Service bus is offered as part of free trial.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

Comment: I was in the new management preview portal, Had to go back to the original site to create service bus namespaces, sql database servers and anything. All are offered as part of the free trial. In order to go back to the previous portal, hover over the green colored preview lint centered at the top of the page and follow the instructions